# Dimension of a subspace (Hermitian matrices)

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, matrices

I have the following exercice from T. Tao's blog which I want to solve:

Suppose that $n \geq2$. Show that the
space of Hermitian matrices with at least one repeated eigenvalue has codimension
3 in the space of all Hermitian matrices.

I know that the dimension of hermitian matrices (over $\mathbb{R}$) of size $n$ is $n^2$. It is not even clear for me that it is actually a subspace we speak about here...

Comment: Well I would try to simultaneously diagonalize the matrices but for that, you would need one of them to be invertible.

Comment: Add the matrix with (1,1,0) on the diagonal (with zeros outside) to the matrix with (0,-1,-1) on the diagonal. The resulting matrix is not in our set? Am I wrong?

Comment: No. It looks like you're right. Do you have a link to the original exercise?

Comment: Link: http://terrytao.wordpress.com/2010/01/12/254a-notes-3a-eigenvalues-and-sums-of-hermitian-matrices/ Exercice 10

Comment: I cannot make sense of that exercise. Actually, Tao's text right after the exercise mentions that hermitian matrices with distinct eigenvalues are dense in the space of all hermitian matrices, which of course implies that it is not a subspace.

Comment: The density claim seems to be right. No?

Comment: The density claim is true. Maybe he means something special by codimension that doesn't require the set to be a vector space.

Comment: The expression 'space of all Hermitian matrices' is also a bit strange for me, as if one could add matrices of different sizes...